# Function that creates a new object with properties set to the values of the input objects specific key in typescript

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
type namedObject = {
    name: string
}

declare function createObjectWithKey<TObjects extends namedObject[]>(...namedObject: TObjects): {
    [key in TObjects[number]['name']]: number
}

const a = createObjectWithKey({
    name: 'test'
}, {
    name: 'test2'
});

/** What I would want here, is that a be typed as an object that has a "test" and "test2" property, which values should be "number", like this
 * 
 * type createdObjectType = {
 *     'test': number,
 *     'test2': number
 * }
 */
```

How could I write the functions signature, so that the return type is an object which I want?

Link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAdghgWwgEwPICMBWEDGwoC8UA3gFBQWyIQBcUAzsAE4CWMA5qQL6mnK4AbOE2gAzAK4w8LAPYwoOEXGAQM2PAHUWwABYBpCCAA8AFTW5g9KBAAeKmMivwkaLBYDaAXQB8ACgB0gc4o5nh0Zm549ACUdGSUUO4A1oZQbFAR6pbuMOII6BBMnu4A5MElnp50ufmF3Lw4coxQcIQKSiqhwFq6BiC%208ZTBdCUqjCXcADQk5EPUI2PAAEwTXNEA3LwA9ABUO1AaOspQAJJQAO4y4gLIF3Aw%20DqFENMsVrrHrQVQoJC3cFZ7lAZJF8B9HgCWlAAESLaEtBwwxZLeFgJgySBMUDTc46Fg4HRQABucAE4ggVnoOiuNyg32hNQKTGh0wELBSPzx9HI%20x5P3A0EUEGUIVBJgFbXi%20wSowpwBK1TyTMmfJlyIVsCVdSg%20x4Oq2QA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work by slightly changing your function and adding `as const`.

```js
type namedObject = {
    name: string
}

declare function createObjectWithKey<TObjects extends readonly namedObject[]>(namedObject: TObjects): {
    [key in TObjects[number]['name']]: number
}

const a = createObjectWithKey([{
    name: 'test'
}  , {
    name: 'test2'
}] as const);
```

It works because when you give `as const`, TS treats the whole array as an immutable thing. It knows that the name will not be any random string, it will only be these specific strings. That is, `typeof namedObject[0].name` is not `string`, it's `"test"`.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAdghgWwgEwPICMBWEDGwoC8UA3gFBQWyIQBcUAzsAE4CWMA5qQL6mnK4AbOE2gAzAK4w8LAPYwoOEXGAQM2PAHUWwABYBpCCAA8AFTW5g9KBAAeKmMitLkcgSCpI0WCwG0AugB8ABTwnuZ4dGbeePQAlHRklFA+ANaGUGxQUeqWPjDiCOgQTH4+AOShEGV+fnT5hcXcvDhyjFBwhApKKuHAWroGIEE+iZSVdGUqjGXcFAA0JORj1BNTwABMM1x+7VYtMIyxANy8APQAVOdQGjrKUACSUADuMuICyM9wMPg6xRALLCsujuHSKUFAkA+cCsXygMmi+GBP2h7SgACI1mj2g50Wt1liwEwZJAmKAFk8dCwcDooAA3OACcQQKz0HSvd5QMFo+pFJhohYCFhpcGU+jkK7i8HgaCKCDKFC9EzSzqJK5JSbM4BlOoFXlzSXqvHa2C6xpQK48c2nIA)

Comment: Beat me to it. You can even do without changing the signature and just add `as const` after every object in the function call.

Comment: yes, but it seemed inconvinent

Comment: Could you explain why does it work like this? I mean, what does the "as const" part do?

Comment: added an explanation